# OpenGL surfaced Qt 6.5 application window not responding

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, qtopengl

I tried to run basic OpenGL example in Qt 6.5 where I only create OpenGL surfaced window. Code is short and clear but I can't see what is missing...

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.setTitle("OpenGL basic");
    w.resize(640,480);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QOpenGLWindow>

class MainWindow : public QOpenGLWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    virtual void initializeGL();
    virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    virtual void paintGL();
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

- I excluded methods others than constructor and destructor because they are empty.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

I hope my question is clear and not so long. Thank you!

**.pro file:**

```
QT       = core gui
QT += opengl

LIBS        += -lopengl32 -lglu32

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = OpenGL
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++17

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h
```

Here is the result I get:
[image: My application output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for few days I found solution on my own.

In Qt 6.5 for OpenGL, they are using **QOpenGLWidget**.

On this link you can find documentation about QOpenGLWidget: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwidget.html